Trouble in understanding a thing or two about wave equations in a PDE course.
I was studying the book "Linear Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" by Lokenath Debnath and Tyn-Myint U.
There was a chapter dedicated to wave equations and I am having a tough time understanding a portion of it.
Firstly, the section started with solving the wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}.$
I was able to find the general solution  by the method of reducing the given PDE  to a canonical form. The general solution was, $$u(x,t)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct),$$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are arbitrary functions provided both can be twice differentiated.
Next, the book went on to calculate the solution of this PDE by applying the initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x), u_t(x,0)=g(x), x\in\Bbb R.$
Using this we find the particular solution to be, $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+ct)-f(x-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\tau)d\tau \tag 1$ This was called the d'Alembert solution of the Cauchy problem for the one-dimensional wave equation.
One thing, the book asked me to note was that this $u(x,t)$ as calculated in $(1)$ depends only on the values of $f$ and $g$ in the interval, $[x-ct,x+ct],$ for every point $(x,t)$ in the domain of the function $u.$ This interval $[x-ct,x+ct],$ is thus called the domain of dependence of the variables $(x,t).$
However, I don't understand a word in the paragraph that follows:

It follows from the d’Alembert solution that, if an initial displacement or an initial velocity is located in a small neighborhood of some point $(x_0, t_0),$ it can influence only the area $t>t_0$ bounded by two characteristics $x−ct=$ constant and $x+ct=constant$ with slope $\pm(1/c)$ passing through the point $(x_0,t_0),$ as shown in the figure below.

This means that the initial displacement propagates with the speed $dx/dt=c,$ whereas the effect of the initial velocity propagates at all speeds upto c.This infinite sector R in this figure is called the range of influence of the point $(x_0,t_0).$

I think what they want to say is, that, if there is a displacement in a neighborhood of the point $(x_0,t_0)$ it can only influence the points lying in the area where, $t>t_0$ bounded by two characteristics $x−ct=$ constant and $x+ct=constant$ with slope $\pm(1/c)$ passing through the point (x_0,t_0),as shown in the figure.
But what do they mean, when they say,

This means that the initial displacement propagates with the speed $dx/dt=c,$ whereas the effect of the initial velocity propagates at all speeds upto c.

Well, what is "initial displacement" and how does it propagates with the speed $dx/dt=c.$ Also, what is the meaning of the phrase, "the effect of the initial velocity propagates at all speeds upto $c$" ?
Any help regarding these issues will be greatly appreciated.
One thing about my background is that I am an undergraduate student pursuing a Bachelor's degree in Mathematics. I am not much educated in physics and I have only a basic idea of it. I think this is the reason why I am facing issues like this. Can someone suggest a remedy for this problem (, if there is any)?

Surely you meant to write $u(x,t)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct)$

The "initial displacement" is like disturbance confined in the light cone and cannot escape out of it (some called principle of causality). I guess you are interested in Feynman's Lectures on Physics, vol. I

@WW1 Thanks for pointing out ghe typo! Fixed it.

Best guess: 1). The "initial displacement" is the information, here wave travels along $x-$axis. Integral interval $[x−ct, x+ct]$ are boundaries cut through by the two characteristic lines $x\pm ct=\mathrm{const}$ through the point $(x,t)$. This interval is called the domain/range of dependence for the solution at $(x,t)$ and the solution at later $(x,t)$ is governed by the initial conditions (Cauchy data). 2). "the effect of the initial velocity propagates at all speeds up to c" means that the initial $\dot{x}(0)$ will propagates within the domain/range of influence with maximum speed $c$.

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be functions supported only on a small interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. What will be the support of $u(\cdot,t)$?
